# Copying specific values in a column, based on conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a project that I need to make a cumulative frequency graph for. I have all 300 values in the "A" column and I have formatted each value that is greater than or equal to 1.98 in green, and the rest red. How if possible, would I only copy values in red or green to another column?

Additionally, ex. if I was to try to find the frequency of values between 1 to 1.25, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: I don't think you can selectively copy based on format without using Javascript. Also you can probably use COUNTIFS() to count the values between 1 and 1.25. Try these and get back if you face difficulties - but show what you have tried.

Comment: Possible work around would be to get the values in another column based on this condition only as (>=1.98) or vice versa by using importrange or query formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those in green: `=filter(A:A,A:A>=1.98)`
For those in red: `=filter(A:A,A:A<1.98)`